# Ms access 2010 check if new record using macro

Tags: ms-access-2010

How is it possible to check if current record is new using macro builder? 
I could find a code to do it using code builder but it seems it is not possible to use both at once, or is it? I have some actions set up using macro builder so I would like to continue. 
Thank you for help.

EDIT: For entering new data I use form. By new record I mean a blank record when on the form.

Comment: Sorry if my question is a bit odd but what is your definition of a new record?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf I mean a blank record inside a form.

Comment: @user1031743 It is easier to convert a Macro to VBA, so you can streamline everything in VBA, which is far too easy to work with.

Comment: @PaulFrancis I wanted to use macro because I read somewhere that VBA does not work when using access online in a server. Probably that is misinterpreted info by me?